# How add filter conditions with the parenthesis in 'N/search' module filters

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, filter, netsuite

I want to add the filter conditions using the parenthesis in 'N/Search 'Module.

I'm getting the adding of parenthesis "()" with conditions in Netsuite Saved Search Options (IN User Interfaces) but i'm not getting the adding of conditions within parenthesis in the "SuiteScript 2.0 version" Filter Arrays.

I want add the conditions within the parenthesis like this on the below image:

[![How to filter conditions with the parenthesis on the filter array(SuiteScript)][1]][1]

**My Code:**

```
filters = [
  ['custrecord_employee_name', 'is', employeeId], 'AND'
  ['custrecord_item_category', 'is', ItemCategoryId], 'AND',
  ['custrecord_commissions_owner', 'is', BookOwnerID], 'AND',
  ['custrecord_form', 'is', formId], 'AND',
  (
    ['custrecord_from_date', 'onorbefore', createdDate], 'OR'
    ['custrecord_from_date', 'onorafter', createdDate]
  ), 'AND',
  (
    ['custrecord_end_date', 'onorbefore', endDate], 'OR',
    ['custrecord_end_date', 'onorafter', endDate]
  )
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using filter expressions, you group conditions together with new layers of Arrays. In your code, you simply replace your parentheses with square brackets. Also, make sure you have declared `filters` with `var` somewhere in your function so that it is not global.

```js
var filters = [ /* use var to avoid global */
  ['custrecord_employee_name', 'is', employeeId], 'AND'
  ['custrecord_item_category', 'is', ItemCategoryId], 'AND',
  ['custrecord_commissions_owner', 'is', BookOwnerID], 'AND',
  ['custrecord_form', 'is', formId], 'AND',
  [ /* array here instead of parens */
    ['custrecord_from_date', 'onorbefore', createdDate], 'OR'
    ['custrecord_from_date', 'onorafter', createdDate]
  ], 'AND',
  [ /* and again here */
    ['custrecord_end_date', 'onorbefore', endDate], 'OR',
    ['custrecord_end_date', 'onorafter', endDate]
  ]
];
```

All that said, I am not quite sure what your date filters are accomplishing. For both `createdDate` and `endDate`, it looks like they can be any of `on`, `before`, or `after` their corresponding field on the record, which is basically any date at all.

What is it that you are actually trying to retrieve with these filters?

Comment: Hi Erictgrubaugh, I have Edited My Question with the Requirement, My filters trying to work based on the Requiement.